# android horizontal progress bar on white background honeycomb

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-3.0-honeycomb

On Honeycomb, if I add a horizontal progress bar to the layout of an activity with white background and 'Light' theme, it can't be viewed because it is white as well. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have anything setting the visibility of your progress bar?  I'm using the same configuration with no problems.